# Child Function Calls Parent Function Instead

Tags: c++

I'm having difficulties trying to get a child function to work:

#### .h file

```
class Parent {
    int id;
    public:
        virtual int getid();
} 

class Child : public Parent {
    int id;
    public:
        int getid();
}
```

#### .cc file

```
Parent::Parent( int num ) {
    id = num;
}

int Parent::getid() {
    cout << "Parent!"; 
    return id;
}

Child::Child( int num ) : Parent(num) {
    id = num;
}

int Child::getid() {
    cout << "Child!";
    return id;
}
```

When I make `Child kid = Child(0);` and call `kid.getid();`, I would get `Parent!` instead of `Child!`.

What is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Return types (specifically, `int`) are missing from the definitions of `Parent::getid()` and `Child::getid()`.

Comment: oops, fixed that (that wasn't part of the problem)

Comment: There's a few syntax errors in this.  Is this the actual code?

Comment: You should not redefine `id` in `Child`. If you need to use `id` in `Child`, set it to `protected` access.

Comment: no, I didn't copy directly but its similar to my code. I'm just curious as to why even though I set my Parent class function to virtual and defined it in my Child class, it still calls the parent function.

Comment: @Kirin it seem that the problem doesn't come from this code (except for syntax errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a lot of syntax errors in it.  I couldn't even get it to compile.  Here it is fixed with a few notes.  This code does in fact output "Child!"

```
#include <iostream>

class Parent {
    protected:
        //Don't redeclare id in child -- have it protected if you want child
        //to have access to it.
        int id;
    public:
        //The constructor must be delcared the same way as other member functions
        Parent(int num);
        virtual int getid();
};

class Child : public Parent {
    public:
        //Once again, the constructor must be declared
        Child(int num);
        int getid();
};

//Initializer lists should be used when possible
Parent::Parent( int num ) : id(num) {
    //id = num;
}

int Parent::getid() {
    std::cout << "Parent!"; 
    return id;
}

//Just call the Parent constructor -- no need to assign inside of the child constructor
Child::Child( int num ) : Parent(num)
{ }

int Child::getid() {
    std::cout << "Child!";
    return id;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Child kid(5);
    std::cout << kid.getid() << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip about "protected" - I'll double check my coding to see if it still produces the parent function call.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your problem, with minimum fix, it does print out `Child!`

http://ideone.com/zR3wTm